# how to stop joomla 3.x from storing guest sessions?

Tags: session, joomla

Joomla stores 3 rows in #__sessions table for any visits of the site.
It is a disaster when you site is on shared hosts and will have a huge overload on mysql.
Is there a way to stop Joomla from storing that much data in #__sessions table?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, without core-hacks, I am afraid this is not possible.

Look into using another session handler, such as APC or memcache(d) to reduce the load on the database.